# Iterate array of object to render a new one

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I work on chat application 
I have an array of objects which contains the sms send
where i have tow sender "14" and "18"
for every sender i want to display the most recent message by time
this my array :

```
const messages = [ 
  {message: "Hello", receiver: "6", sender: "14", time: "12:26 12/11/2019"},
  {message: "help", receiver: "6", sender: "14", time: "12:22 12/11/2019"},
  {message: "me", receiver: "6", sender: "18", time: "12:01 12/11/2019"},
  {message: "Hii", receiver: "6", sender: "18", time: "10:10 12/11/2019"},
  {message: "good ", receiver: "6", sender: "18", time: "09:13 12/11/2019"},
  {message: "ok", receiver: "6", sender: "18", time: "12:26 11/11/2019"},
  {message: "welcoome ", receiver: "6", sender: "14", time: "11:05 12/11/2019"}
];
```

How can i do that please ?
This is extract of my code reactjs where i work in `this.props.chats` extract of const messages.

```
function parseTime(timeStr) {
  const fields = timeStr.split(":").map(parseInt);
  return fields[0] * 60 + fields[1];
}

let result = this.props.chats.reduce((map, item) => {
  if (!map[item.sender] || parseTime(map[item.sender].time) < parseTime(item.time)) {
    map[item.sender] = item;
  }
  return map;
}, {});
var messageInbox = Object.values(result)

console.log("Latest messages:", messageInbox);
```

He doesn't render the last message according to the temp.

Comment: Did you try anything? if so, please share what you tried and we'll help if we can

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, what have you tried so far? Please read up on how to ask a proper question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Just use `map`..  `{messages.map(m => <div>{m.message}</div>) }`

Comment: @Keith i want the last send messages not all the message

Comment: Just use all the normal JavaScript array functions like `map` `filter` `sort` etc.  These all work as you expect in React..

Comment: @Keith I made several attempt but i don't found a solution that's why i ask here

Comment: @DarrenSweeney yes check the question please

Answer (score 0):

use [`array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

`messages.sort( a,b => parseTime(b.time) - parseTime(a.time) );`

and then extract the last value:

`lastMsg = messages[messages.length-1];`

Answer (score 0):

Here your Answer:
i change the date and time to time stamp so i can compare it easily.
https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-mcclintock-itwnx

Answer (score 0):

You can `reduce` your items, `sort` them and then get the first element of an array:

```
const senders = messages.reduce((a, c) => {
  a[c.sender] = a[c.sender]  || { data:[]};
  a[c.sender].data.push({ sender: c.sender, message: c.message, time: c.time});
  a[c.sender].data.sort((a, b)=> new Date(b.time) - new Date(a.time))
  return a;
}, {})    

console.log(Object.values(senders).map(s => s.data[0]));
```

```js
const messages = [
  { message: "Hello", receiver: "6", sender: "14", time: "12:26 12/11/2019" },
  { message: "help", receiver: "6", sender: "14", time: "12:22 12/11/2019" },
  { message: "me", receiver: "6", sender: "18", time: "12:01 12/11/2019" },
  { message: "Hii", receiver: "6", sender: "18", time: "10:10 12/11/2019" },
  { message: "good ", receiver: "6", sender: "18", time: "09:13 12/11/2019" },
  { message: "ok", receiver: "6", sender: "18", time: "12:26 11/11/2019" },
  { message: "welcoome ", receiver: "6", sender: "14", time: "11:05 12/11/2019" }
];


const senders = messages.reduce((a, c) => {
  a[c.sender] = a[c.sender]  || { data:[]};
  a[c.sender].data.push({ sender: c.sender, message: c.message, time: c.time});
  a[c.sender].data.sort((a, b)=> new Date(b.time) - new Date(a.time))
  return a;
}, {})


console.log(Object.values(senders).map(s => s.data[0]));
```